# How to get only token Id using flutter stripe from card information?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, flutter-stripe

I need just to create a token from the Card number, expire month/year, and CVC using **flutter-stripe.** Could anyone please suggest to me any complete resources or source code to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the full example of how to generate the token i.e. paymentMethod from the stripe with the credit card info.

For Example:

```html
final cardDetails = CardDetails(
        number: "42424242424242424242,
        expirationMonth: "11",
        expirationYear: "23,
        cvc: "1234,
);
Stripe.instance.dangerouslyUpdateCardDetails(cardDetails);

final billingDetails = BillingDetails(
        email: "john@doe.com",
        name: "John Doe",
        address: Address(
          city: "my city",
          country: "USA",
          line1: "address",
          line2: '',
          state: "NY",
          postalCode: "53535",
        ),
      );
      
/// create payment method
final paymentMethod = await Stripe.instance.createPaymentMethod(
          PaymentMethodParams.card(
              paymentMethodData: PaymentMethodData(billingDetails: billingDetails),
          ),
      );
      
      
print(paymentMethod.id);
```

Comment: So kind of you Suz Zan. It's working nicely but here every data is hard coded. How to show a CardField on the bottom draggable sheet and take value and pass to card details. Should I make take so many TextField as per necessity or is there any default way? Thanks.

Comment: normally I would just write the widgets by myself. But I think the flutter_stripe package has a method to create a credit cards widget that displays all the required fields by itself. You should go through their documentation in detail to know how to achieve that

Comment: I have done it in another way thanks for your cooperation anyway, Dear Suz Zan

Answer (score 0):

I know I am answering late for this question but it can help others It is so simple you can use either flutter_stripe package's widget **CardFormField** or **CardField** to collect the card details of user
like this:

```
CardFormField(
                      style: CardFormStyle(
                        placeholderColor: AppColors.greyColor,
                        textColor: AppColors.greyColor,
                        borderColor: AppColors.purpleTextColor,
                        backgroundColor:isDarkMode==true?Colors.grey[100]: Colors.white,
                     
                      ),
                    ),
```

CardFormField will create a card form UI provided by Stripe
and now you have card detils you can create token with it by this Stripe methid here is exampel :

```
 var token = await Stripe.instance.createToken(
      const CreateTokenParams.card(
        params: CardTokenParams(
          name: "test",
          address: Address(
            line1: "abc",
            line2: "xyz",
            city: "Alpha",
            state: "Beta",
            country: "xy",
            postalCode: "237482",
          ),
          currency: "ab",
          type: TokenType.Card,
        ),
      ),
    );

    String tokenId=token.id;
```

Comment: So kind of you #Muhammad Hassan Razzaq

Comment: Please provide a full working example. how you use CardFormField() details to create a token?

Comment: @MuhammadRazzak can you please provide full code example for more understanding.